Problems with understanding Solana address ownership
When I put my Solana address to Solscan, it shows this:
Owner: System Program
isOnCurve: True
Does this mean I’m the only one onwer of the wallet? And it is not owned by anyone else or smart contract?
Asking this because when transferring SPL Tokens to my Solana address, Helium HNT Wallet showed following message:
“This is a smart-contract owned account. Are you sure this is the correct address?”
So I’m not sure how to check are their message about my Solana Wallet true or false and should I be worried about it.

The 'owner' shown in Solscan (and Solana Explorer etc) is the owning program, per the other question. You - as the only person with the matching private key for your address - are the only person that has access to your wallet.
You are the person
Asking this because when transferring SPL Tokens to my Solana address, Helium HNT Wallet showed following message:
“This is a smart-contract owned account. Are you sure this is the correct address?”

Also for the "Helium HNT Wallet" message - you normally send specific SPL tokens to an  "Associated Token Account" - a PDA owned by the Token Program that stores your balance of a particular token.
